# wordpress login redirect caching post id

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to restrict my post contents to be shown only to logged in members. Here is the code:

```
function my_page_template_redirect()
{
   // $wp = get_queried_object();
   // echo "<pre>";
   // print_r($wp);
   // echo "</pre>";
    if( is_singular( 'property' ) )
    {
        if(!is_user_logged_in())
        {
            wp_redirect( get_permalink(103) );
            exit();
        }

    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```

Its working fine, but the problem is. Like say i tried to visit "Hello World" it redirects me to the  Login Page containing "TML login form shortcode" When i login it follows TML redirection and i can navigate to post i wanted to read. But the problem is i can't see that "Hello World" only post, but can see all other of same type same restriction.

Seems like wordpress saving that Post ID. Suggestion please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.. `auth_rediect()` did the trick. I replaced `wp_redirect` to `auth_redirect()`

So the final code is:

```
function my_page_template_redirect()
{

    if( is_singular( 'property' ) )
    {
        if(!is_user_logged_in())
        {
            auth_redirect();
        }

    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```